# Creating a Dump file using Mac

Tags: mysql, dump

I tried creating a MySQL dump file on a Mac and the tables nor data are  loading even with Data and Structure is selected for a data export into a self contained file.

the data export Wizard to create a dump file works fine on a PC but the database I need to copy with all the data is on a Mac.

Comment: Can you do it from a Terminal window with the `mysqldump` command?

Comment: Please explain how you are attempting to do this. "data export Wizard" is workbench, phpmyadmin, something else?

Comment: I used the Data Export Wizard in Workbench